# Unable to create valid screenshot using browser.takescreenshot()

Tags: jasmine, protractor

This is the code that I have in the afterEach block.

```
afterEach(function() {
        jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new function () {
            this.specDone = function (result) {

                console.log("result is :"+result);
                if (result.failedExpectations.length > 0) {
                    browser.takeScreenshot().then(function(png) {

                        console.log("png is :"+png);
                        console.dir(png);
                        var stream = fs.createWriteStream(specName.description+".png");
                        var stream2 = fs.createWriteStream(specName.description+"2.png");
                        stream.write(new Buffer(png,'utf8', function (err)
                        {
                            if (err) throw err
                            console.log('File saved.')
                        }));
                        stream2.write(new Buffer(png,'base64'));
                        stream.end();
                        stream2.end();
                    });
                }
            };
        });
```

But none of the photo viewers is able to open the files. Any insights as to what is going wrong is highly appreciated.

System is windows 10 and browser Firefox 46.*

The console.log of the png returned by the browser.takeScreenshot() is as below:
png is :{"name":"screenshot","sessionId":"c18f3e08-9da0-4c71-9a10-391bab714e7a","status":0,"value":"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

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why `takeShotshot()` method returns the entire JSON object instead of just the base64 value for the screenshot. In your case, you can check whether the object returned by takeScreenShot methods contains any key with name `value`. If value is is present, then use it to get base64 value of the screenshot.

```
browser.takeScreenshot().then(function(png) {
  var base64Value = png.hasOwnProperty("value") ? png.value : png;
  var stream = fs.createWriteStream(specName.description+".png");
  var stream2 = fs.createWriteStream(specName.description+"2.png");
  stream.write(new Buffer(png,'utf8', function (err)
    {
       if (err) throw err
            console.log('File saved.')
        }));
   stream2.write(new Buffer(base64Value,'base64'));
   stream.end();
   stream2.end();
})
```

Comment: Yeah .. even I am surprised why `takeScreenshot()` returns a JSON instead of just the base64 value .. I am using `Protractor 4.0.10` and I see only the encoded value and I see everything good with screenshots generated

Comment: I checked the ChangeLog of Protractor and dont see any new changes .. But anyway +1 to your answer for handling both scenarios when its an array or the encoded value